# Got a multiple-entry Schengen visa but have to cancel the original trip. Do I get to keep the visa?

Tags: schengen, eu, visa-cancellation

I got a multiple-entry tourist Schengen visa, but will likely have to cancel the original trip due to personal reasons.

I'd like to keep the visa active, however, as I intend to make the trip some time later this year.

Do I need to inform the destination country's embassy about the change in my plans?

Does this mean my multiple-entry visa will likely be canceled by the embassy?